# UDP cannot connect to anything other than 127.0.0.1

Tags: networking, udp

Im not too sure why this wont work. My application works fine if the client and server are ran on the same PC hence the 127.0.0.1 but it wont connect to my other laptop using IP 82.41.108.125 which is the IP of that device.

Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: UDP doesn't 'connect' to anything. You mean 'send to' or 'receive from'.

Comment: I edited my post to add some information that may help you understand things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your firewall could quite possibly be blocking the port assuming all of your coding is working fine - try opening up the port number you're running the application on (in the client/server comptuers' firewall options).

**Some additional information that should shed some light on things**

Networked devices use ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) and RARP (Reverse Address Resolution Protocol) to map IPs to link layer (MAC) addresses and back.  Your network interface card (the thing that plugs into your ethernet cable) will have a unique MAC address on both computers.  Each PC has an IP configured for it which is used by higher level protocols (those in the Network Layer).

Computer A will know computer B's IP address (and it will be different from computer A's) if your program works correctly.  When computer A goes to send to comptuer B, assuming they're directly connected and not going through a router or something in between, computer A's link layer will need to translate that IP for comptuer B into a MAC address it can use.  It does this by sending out a broadcast to all network PCs on the same sub network asking "Hey, is this your IP!?" essentially.  The one that has an IP matching the broadcasted one yes, "Yes, it's mine - and here's my MAC address so you can talk directly to me."

So, if two computers have the same IP this all goes to hell :) don't do it - give them unique IPs and make sure that comptuer A transmits to the same UDP port and IP that computer B is listening on as well.  communications work in {IP, Port} pairs - its like a telephone number and area code.

**Also...**

As said by EJP - UDP is a connectionless protocol - computer A just sends to computer B and hopes that computer B is listening correctly.  If computer B wasn't listening or was but wasn't in the right state to process the data, the data will simply be dropped and lost.  Computer A will not know that this happened.  If you want reliable communications where it will keep trying and you will have assurance that compuer B received computer A's data then use TCP instead - it does a 3 way handshake to establish a connection and uses acknowledgements to ensure data is retransmitted when it doesn't reach the other end.

Comment: both my laptops have the same IP right now, the firewall is now disabled but data still isnt arriving. any Ideas?

Comment: Give the laptops different IPs first-off - they shouldn't have the same.  I'm surprised they'll even talk to each other or be allowed on the network with the same IP.  If they still won't talk to each other you should probably toss some code up for people to look at.  Maybe you're not using INADDR_ANY to accept information from all interfaces or something like that.

Comment: "both my laptops have the same IP right now." *That's the problem.* Why should laptop A put anything on the wire to B when the IP address it is sending to is its own?

Comment: thanks for the help, I dont know why the laptops have the same IP its not like I have set them as static IP's. Im not too fussed about lost packets as there is an infrastructure I am building around UDP to handle lost packets. This is going to be for a game and thats why I am using UDP, it may incorporate some features of TCP but right now it seems unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're listening on localhost (127.0.0.1) and don't accept other traffic. Use a wildcard address.

Check on the server with `netstat -npu`.

If that's not the case then it's probably firewall issue, verify with `tcpdump` or wireshark.

Comment: wireshark was showing that the port was unreachable however after turning off the firewall that stopped. Sever still is not receiving anything from the client though

Comment: I use htonl(INADDR_ANY) as the wildcard

Comment: hmm.. weird. do you check return values of *all* the syscalls? is port number OK? maybe it's already used. ehm.. I've run out of ideas. If it works locally and you receive traffic from remote it should work as well..

Answer (score 0):

Check firewall on your laptop... Most of the time that acts as spoilsport.